# Show that a holomorphic function is polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function for which there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$ and a $C>0$ so that
>
> $|f(z)|\leq C(1+|z|^n)$
>
> Show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$.

I've tried to proof this statement with Liouville's theorem but I don't know which function to take. $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{1+z^n}$ isn't necessarily bounded, $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{1+|z|^n}$ is bounded by C but not holomorphic. Any hints?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184258/show-that-f-is-a-polynomial-of-degree-le-n/2184270#2184270

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Cauchy's inequalities. Namely, for any $r>0$, we have the estimate
$$|f^{(k)}(0)| \leqslant k! r^{-k} |f|_{\partial B_r(0)}.$$
Now consider what happens when $k>n$. It is important that you remember the proof of Liouville's theorem rather than its conclusion. The point is that if the function
$$ r\longmapsto M(r) = |f|_{\partial B_r(0)} $$
grows slowly, you can pin down what $f$ is. In particular, if it grows at most like a polynomial, $f$ is a polynomial, if it is constant, then so is $f$, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about Cauchy's inequalities. In complex analysis everything seems to have something to do with those.